# How to close the current fragment by using Button like the back button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-finish

I have try to close the current fragment by using Imagebutton.

I am in Fragment-A and it will turn to the Fragment-B when I click the button.

And when I click the button at Fragment-B , it will turn to the Fragment-C and close the Fragment-B.

If I click the back button at Fragment-C , it will back to the Fragment-A.

The code I have try is like the following

```
camera_album = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_album);

camera_album.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

                    closefragment();
        Fragment fragment = FileBrowserFragment.newInstance(null, null, null) ;
        MainActivity.addFragment(LocalFileBrowserFragment.this, fragment) ;


    }
});

private void closefragment() {
    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
}
```

When I click the back button at fragment-B , it turn to the Fragment-C.

But when I click the back button on Fragment-C , it doesn't back to the Fragment-A.
It back to the empty background. If I want to back to Fragment-A , I have to click the back button once again.

SO , it seem doesn't close the current fragment complete.

How to finish the current fragment like the back button of Android ?

Comment: What is this `MainActivity.addFragment(LocalFileBrowserFragment.this, fragment)`??. you need to add the fragment to backstak and pop the same accordingly

Comment: There has add the fragment in function addFragment.

Comment: add fragment to what and an activity method??

Comment: getActivity().onBackPressed(); can do this

Answer (score 87, accepted):

From Fragment A, to go to B, replace A with B and use `addToBackstack()` before `commit()`.

Now From Fragment B, to go to C, first use `popBackStackImmediate()`, this will bring back A. Now replace A with C, just like the first transaction.

Comment: for usinf popStackImmediate() :->
 getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                  
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate() ;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

Answer (score 181):

I changed the code from

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

to

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

And it pops out the top fragment

Comment: This worked for me context.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this@MyFragment).commit()

Comment: With fragment of type androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, this seems to leave the fragment header.  Therefore I have my main app, with the popped fragment header still showing.  The getActivity().onBackPressed() seem to work better for me.

Comment: Don't forget to use "getSupportFragmentManager()" in case "getFragmentManager()" isn't working for you

Comment: Unfortunately this is outdated. Use: OnBackPressedCallback from now on.

Answer (score 88):

For those who need to figure out simple way

Try `getActivity().onBackPressed();`

Comment: getActivity() can be null lot of times.

Comment: @ArpitJ. it's only null before onAttach() is called, a fragment can't live without an activity.

Comment: @TamimAttafi True, but I was referring to cases like rotation or activity is finished and due to some reason fragment instance is still there then it will return null.

Comment: `popBackStack()` and `popBackStackImmediate()` are more direct ways of popping the topmost fragment without simulating a button press.

Using `onBackPressed()` triggers `OnBackPressedCallback`s; if in the future you want to handle Back button presses specifically, you'll have to switch to `popBackStack()`/`popBackStackImmediate()` to avoid triggering the callbacks programmatically.

Comment: You put this code inside the Fragment's buttons's onclick method.

Comment: Terrible solution. Altho it gives the results initially, it can cause many problems once you start overriding OnBackPress or if let's say the keyboard is open or something, the back press you initiate will only close the keyboard not the fragment. And these are only a few of the many possible problems you can encounter with this solution. User popBackStack() or  popBackStackImmediate().

Comment: 'onBackPressed()' is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

**Try this:**

```
public void removeFragment(Fragment fragment){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a Kotlin way of doing this, I have created button in fragment layout and then set onClickListner in onViewCreated.

> according to @Viswanath-Lekshmanan comment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
{
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

     btn_FragSP_back.setOnClickListener {
        activity?.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: this closes the activity, not the fragment

Comment: How can we do this if we have to double backpress to close the activity?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this logic because it is worked for me.

```
frag_profile profile_fragment = new frag_profile();

boolean flag = false;
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void profile_Frag(){
    if (flag == false) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.transition_anim0, R.anim.transition_anim1);
        transaction.replace(R.id.parentPanel, profile_fragment, "FirstFragment");
        transaction.commit();
        flag = true;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (flag == true) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        transaction.remove(profile_fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        flag = false;
    }
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);   // ft is FragmentTransaction
```

So, when you press **back-key**, the current activity (which holds multiple fragments) will load previous fragment rather than finishing itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
Button ok= view.findViewById(R.id.btSettingOK);
Fragment me=this;
ok.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
     getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(me).commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This simple code actually removes the current fragment view by a OK or Close button on it. I use it for quitting a light setting panel displayed as a Fragment and go back to the Activity. Sorry for this trick but under Android 8, I think it is not so practical to manage multiple Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle the action more specifically with the back button you can use the following method:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            onCloseFragment();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Fragments `onCreateView(...)` you can remove a view by calling `container.removeView(view);`.
So if you want to remove the fragment, then `view` should be the return value of `onCreateView`,

**for example**

```
    public View onCreateView(...){
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragments_layout,container,false);
        //Do something
        finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                container.removeView(view);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For remove current fragment B and navigate to stack back (other fragment A):

```
private fun navigateToBackStack() {
    requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .remove(this)
        .commit()
    requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
}
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

If you use JetPack Navigation, write:

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using DialogFragment, just call `.dismiss()`.

Answer (score -14):

Try this one

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Try explaining your answer more , so that its easy for OP and other people to understand the answer who come back to this question in future

Comment: this closes the whole activity, not the fragment

Comment: It helped me. 
Those who want more information may google it. No need to copypaste here official documentation.

Comment: If you are using BottomNavigationView which usually has one activity, this command will close the app instead of getting back to the previous fragment.