# How can I set onClick to close fragment in ImageView?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I cannot get this working using most of the solutions here. Please check my code that starts the fragment on the activity.

```
public void selectFrag() {
    Fragment fr;

    fr = new SelectionFragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    //I removed this since my animations give error with FrameLayout
    //fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_down);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_selection, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

On my fragment I have the following that is extending `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_attributes, container, false);

    //Close fragment using close icon
    ImageView close = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.close_fragment);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closefragment();
        }
    });

    return view;
}//End onCreateView Method

private void closefragment() {
    getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

}

My XML contains ImageView inside a RelativeLayout

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/close_fragment"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close_cross"/>
```

How can I set ImageView to listen to click that closes the fragment? I have only one fragment and nothing happens with my code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close the current fragment by using Button like the back button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812922/how-to-close-the-current-fragment-by-using-button-like-the-back-button)

Comment: @Taras Check the code to close fragment I have used, it is exactly the same as the duplicate you linked. This is not working with my ImageView.

Comment: But the code to ADD fragment is different. Pay attention to _use addToBackstack() before commit()_ part of accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `getActivity()` from closefragment()

```
private void closefragment() {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is following:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_selection, fr);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`
```

Comment: Sorry I had tried this code before but I posted the code while I was testing without addToBackStack(). It still does not close the fragment.

Comment: This line:`getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`,  shouldn't it be `getSupportFragmentManager` ?

Comment: Or you can just call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` without `getActivity()`

Comment: I am using import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; hence I call getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

popBackStack(); only reverses your previous transaction. If you want to close this Fragment you should call

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pls.

```
private void closefragment() {
getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); }
```

or this

```
private void closefragment() {
getActivity.finish(); }
```

Comment: Trying to invoke getFragmentManager() on a null object.