# Back button in toolbar not working in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am enabled back button in android fragment using below code.But when I click on it triggers side navigation menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using [view pager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)..?

Comment: @NileshRathod view pager means I am new to android.

Comment: Add setHasOptionsMenu(true); in Your Fragments onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method.

Comment: @ADM i am added setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreateView

Comment: NOt in onCreateView() user it in onCreate().

Comment: post your onCreate()

Comment: @byteC0de what should happen when u click on that back button?

Comment: @Raghavendra want to go previous fragment

Comment: @byteC0de u haven't written any logic to do that? You are just calling activity's onBackpresses()

Comment: @Raghavendra, when I am clicking on back the function onOptionsItemSelected, is not trigering

Comment: @byteC0de but in the question u said **I click on it triggers side navigation menu**

Comment: @Raghavendra yes, but it's now calling from there

Comment: @byteC0de check how to navigate between fragments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812922/how-to-close-the-current-fragment-by-using-button-like-the-back-button

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Use this code inside class where you are initialising toolbar and drawer layout.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// show back button
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        } else {
            //show hamburger
            drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Replace your fragment like below:

```
Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
    android.R.anim.fade_out);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
if (fragment != new HomeFragment()){
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //This line is important
}
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```