# onActivityResult on different fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a 2 fragments in 1 activity, namely, fragment A and fragment B.

From fragment A, I move to fragment B with button (add fragment) and in fragment B I use `startActivityOnResult()` to intent image capture / camera.

Can I call `onActivityOnresult` in fragment A?

I want to finish the fragment B, so I get the `imageUri` on fragment A.

I have tried the following in fragment B, but not working

`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();`

Can you guys tell me how to do it properly?

Here is my code:

Fragment A :

```
 btnSelfieUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sessionHelper.setForceDontShowPinLockOnNextResume(true);
            if (shouldAskPermissions()) {

                askPermissions();
            }
            ((ApplicationActivity) mActivity).clearBackStack();
            ((ApplicationActivity) mActivity).clickTutorialSelfie();
            bSelfieUpload = true;

        }
    });
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case TAKE_PICTURE_KTP:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String path = data.getExtras().getString("uri");
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
                    fileKtp = PhotoUtils.convertToBase64(bitmap);
                    ivKtpDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Glide.with(mActivity)
                            .load(path)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .skipMemoryCache(true)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                            .error(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_photo))
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(ivKtpDone);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Gagal memuat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;

        case TAKE_PICTURE_SELFIE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String path = data.getExtras().getString("uri");
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
                    fileSelfie = PhotoUtils.convertToBase64(bitmap);
                    ivSelfieDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Glide.with(mActivity)
                            .load(path)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .skipMemoryCache(true)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                            .error(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_photo))
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(ivSelfieDone);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Gagal memuat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Fragment b :

```
public void takePhoto() {
    sessionHelper.setForceDontShowPinLockOnNextResume(true);
    HCIDAppController.getInstance().setEnablePinLock(false);
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, HCIDCameraActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("cameraId", TAKE_PICTURE);
       startActivityForResult(intent, 4);
    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/" + Math.random() + ".jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 4);
    }
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
}
```

Comment: You can do this convert your bitmap into base64 string save it and use it anywhere you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get **onActivityResult()** callback inside your activity as both fragments are part of the same activity.

Once you get called inside **onActivityResult()** check the request code and **pop the current fragment(Fragment B).**

So now you have only fragment A on your activity, so create another method of onActivityResult() inside your FragmentA and perform your operation.

Refer below link for pop up the fragment.

[How to close the current fragment by using Button like the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812922/how-to-close-the-current-fragment-by-using-button-like-the-back-button)

Comment: where i can pop the fragment B ? in wich line of code?

Comment: inside onActivityResult() of activity where you found proper requestCode.

Comment: @Borom1r: is this works for you? or still struggling?