# how to finish fragment on single activity app android

Tags: java, android

I have a `Splash_Screen` fragment. After navigating to the next fragment, I want my `SplashScreen` fragment to be `destroyed`. How can I do this?
I use `getActivity().finish` and this finishes my app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close the current fragment by using Button like the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812922/how-to-close-the-current-fragment-by-using-button-like-the-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

Once you move from Splash_Screen Fragment to next fragment,Remove Your Splash_Screen Fragment form 'BACKSTACK'. So Your Splash_Screen Fragment will not open again.
How this works for you.

For more information see below thread from Stack Over Flow:

[How to clear Fragment backstack in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107005/how-to-clear-fragment-backstack-in-android)

Comment: tanks for answer i use navigation component and i dont no how to use Backstack on navigation component